# How to filter outlier rows from Spark Dataframe based on distance to previous valid row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm processing geospatial data using Spark 2.0 Dataframes with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |-- lon: double (nullable = true)
 |-- accuracy: double (nullable = true)
 |-- track_id: long (nullable = true)
```

I have seen that there are jumps of the location signal to a complete different place. The strange thing is, that the signal then remains for a certain time, say aound 25 seconds or 5 samples at the remote location and then jumps back to where I stand.

I'd like to remove outliers by calculating the speed between the current and the last valid row by calculating the speed between the points. 
If the speed is above a given threshold, the current row should be dropped and the last valid row remains the same.
If the speed is below the threshold the current row is added to the result data frame and becomes the new last valid row.

I tried to accomplish this by using the mapPartition function:

```
case class OutlierFilterTrackEntry(val dateSec: Long, val track_id: Long, val lat: Double, val lon: Double, val accuracy: Double)

def filterOutlier(iter : Iterator[OutlierFilterTrackEntry]) :  Iterator[OutlierFilterTrackEntry] = {
    val maxSpeed = 1000 / 3.6 // 1000 km/h in m/s
    val buf = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[OutlierFilterTrackEntry]
    var lastValid : OutlierFilterTrackEntry = null
    while (iter.hasNext){
        val cur = iter.next;
        if(lastValid == null){
            lastValid = cur
        }else{
            //val distance = calculateDistance(cur.lat, cur.lon, lastValid.lat, lastValid.lon)
            val distance = GeometryEngine.geodesicDistanceOnWGS84(new Point(cur.lon, cur.lat), new Point(lastValid.lon, lastValid.lat))
            val diffTime = (cur.dateSec - lastValid.dateSec) 
            val speed = distance / diffTime
            println(speed)
            if(speed < maxSpeed) {
                lastValid = cur
                buf.append(cur)
            }
        }
    }
    buf.toList.iterator
}

val numPartitions = tracks6.select($"track_id").distinct().count.toInt
println(numPartitions)
val partitionedTracks = tracks6.select(col("date").cast("BigInt").alias("dateSec"), $"track_id", $"lat", $"lon", $"accuracy")
                               .orderBy($"date")
                               .repartition(numPartitions, $"track_id")

val tracksWithoutOutliers = partitionedTracks
                                    .as[OutlierFilterTrackEntry]
                                    .mapPartitions(filterOutlier)

println(tracksWithoutOutliers.count)
tracksWithoutOutliers.toDF.show(400)
```

But I get the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec, value: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec@711a5138)
    - field (class: linebb5d1438a8a14914aa58d2465d24fa2a59.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: windowSpecAllPrev, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec)
```

Any other approaches are welcome.

Comment: There is no instance of `WindowSpec` in your code. Find place where it is and either move it out of scope or make it `@transient`. Also method you use is not reliable.

Comment: Many Thanks. I used WindowSpec above to create the tracks Dataframe. But the only option I see to get it completely out of my dataframe here is to persist and reload the data. Or are there any other options? I'm aware that the code is not reliable in the case that if the first value is wrong, not where it should be, then it wil not work.

Comment: Also it doesn't cover partition boundaries. It would be better to use UDAF / window functions.

Comment: Why does it not cover partition boundaries? I was thinking repartitioning based on track_id will put all records with the same track_id in the same partition. If then mapPartitions is used, each partition will be processes separately so that the function filterOutliers will be called for each partition.  Is this a wrong assumption? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Remember that data comes from different partitions and it requires a shuffle. There is no guarantee you get order from `orderBy` as far as I know.

Comment: Ok. I was not aware of that. I thought that each call of filterOutliers function from mapPartions would pass a whole partition. Thank you so much!

Comment: It will pass a whole partition but a) each partition can contain more than one key b) there is no guarantee key will be ordered (I think). Data comes from different partitions so you have block_from_on, block_from_another, ...